# 'IPAddress' does not name a type with Arduino library Ethernet2

Tags: arduino, ethernet, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I have an Arduino Ethernet2 shield.
I read it has some problem with the default library.

I downloaded the Ethernet2 library from [Tinker](https://code.google.com/p/tinkerit/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FEthernet2%20library%2FEthernet2), put the folder in the Arduino libraries path and copied some missing files from the old Ethernet library.

I tried the webserver example of the Ethernet library. However including the Ethernet2 library gives the error `'IPAddress' does not name a type`.

Does anyone have the same problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if the libraries are installed correctly, and/or they aren't mixed with other libraries.

Comment: I would recommend re-installing the library. There is probably a conflict with some other files.